# Custom registration form. Confirm password

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration, django-custom-user

I used custom form for register users. I want do validation for confirm password.
forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    '''Register for new users'''
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = {'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

template:

```
<div class="input-group register">
     {{ form.password.errors }}
     <label for="id_password1">Password: </label>
     {{ form.password1 }}
</div>
<div class="input-group register">
    {{ form.password.errors }}
    <label for="id_password2">Confirm password: </label>
    {{ form.password2 }}                            
</div>
```

views.py

```
def registration_view(request):
context = {}
context.update(csrf(request))
context['form'] = RegistrationForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        newuser = auth.authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password2']
        )
        auth.login(request, newuser)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        context['form'] = form

return render(request, '/registration.html', context)
```

How can I add validation for password(also confirm password)?

Comment: This is a `UserCreation` form, so that means that it is already implemented.

Comment: Yes, I tried this form like {{form}}, but i not satisfied view. On my template doesn't work compare two password.

Comment: Thank you, Willem Van Onsem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You inherit from [**`UserCreationForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L65). This form already does that for you.

Indeed: the `clean_password2` will validate that the two passwords are the same:

> ```
>     def clean_password2(self):
>         password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
>         password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
>         if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
>             raise forms.ValidationError(
>                 self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
>                 code='password_mismatch',
>             )
>         return password2
> ```

The `_post_clean` function will validate that the password is a valid password:

> ```
>     def _post_clean(self):
>         super()._post_clean()
>         # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
>         # by super().
>         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
>         if password:
>             try:
>                 password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
>             except forms.ValidationError as error:
>                 self.add_error('password2', error)
> ```

Finally in the `save()` it will use `.set_password()` to set the password. This is necessary, since Django's `User` model will, like any good user model, *hash* the password.

> ```
>     def save(self, commit=True):
>         user = super().save(commit=False)
>         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
>         if commit:
>             user.save()
>         return user
> ```

You thus should not interfere with these. You here only want to add `first_name` and `last_name`. So you can add that logic with:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    '''Register for new users'''
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

That's all, since the `ModelForm` will take care of that.

Note that `authenticate` in your view is probably not necessary, since if you construct a user, it should authenticate. You can just `login` here:

```
def registration_view(request):
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newuser = form.save()
            auth.login(request, newuser)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, '/registration.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw this decision. And I going to use custom validation for password

Comment: @RustamPulatov: then I suggest that you override the `_post_clean` with your own validation :). But you likely do not have to rewrite the rest of the form :)

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use this in your register template**

```
<form method="post" id="register-account-form">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for field in form %}

                        {% if field.help_text %}
                            <div class="notification error closeable">
                            <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                            <a class="close" href="#"></a>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="notification error closeable">
                            <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                            <a class="close" href="#"></a>
                            </div>

                        {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}


                <div class="input-with-icon-left">
                    <i class="icon-feather-user"></i>
                    {{ form.username }}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find mistake

```
<div class="input-group register">
    {{ form.password1.errors }}
     <label for="id_password1">Пароль: </label>
     {{ form.password1 }}
 </div>
 <div class="input-group register">
     {{ form.password2.errors }}
     <label for="id_password2">Подтвердите пароль: </label>
     {{ form.password2 }}                            
 </div>
```